# Utils - ERROR - Error java.lang.NullPointerException in Selenium

Tags: selenium, apache-poi

Error

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Total rows are 5
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at appops_main_home.LaunchPortalData.passUNamePwd(LaunchPortalData.java:41)
    at appops_main_home.LaunchPortal.TestDataFeed(LaunchPortal.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:923)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: Loginapp
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:923)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at appops_main_home.LaunchPortalData.passUNamePwd(LaunchPortalData.java:41)
    at appops_main_home.LaunchPortal.TestDataFeed(LaunchPortal.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    ... 22 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

This is my code

```
package appops_main_home;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//import utility.Constant;

//import excel.input.login.LaunchPortalData;

public class LaunchPortal
{
    ChromeDriver driver ;

  @Test(dataProvider = "testdata")
 public void Loginapp(String W3ID, String W3Pwd) throws InterruptedException

  {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\KalaivaniBaskaran\\Desktop\\088619\\Selenium\\Jar & drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      driver.get("http://testurl");
      driver.findElement(By.id("desktop")).sendKeys(W3ID);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/input[4]")).sendKeys(W3Pwd);
      driver.findElement(By.id("btn_signin")).click();  

      Assert.assertTrue("Invalid credentials", driver.getTitle().matches("Hybrid Cloud Portal"));
      System.out.println("Login successful");

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void closebrowser()
  {
  driver.quit();
}


  @DataProvider(name="testdata")
  public Object[][] TestDataFeed()
  {
      LaunchPortalData config = new LaunchPortalData("C:\\Users\\KalaivaniBaskaran\\Desktop\\088619\\test excel datas\\Usernamepwd_AppOps.xlsx");

      int r = config.Rowcountcalculator();
      System.out.println("Total rows are "+r);

      Object[][] credentials = new Object[r][2];

      for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
      {
        credentials[i][0] = config.passUNamePwd(0, i, 0);
        credentials[i][1] = config.passUNamePwd(0, i, 1);     
      }
      return credentials;
  }
}
```

and this is the data

```
package appops_main_home;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;


public class LaunchPortalData {

    XSSFWorkbook wb ;
    XSSFSheet sheet0;

 public LaunchPortalData(String excelPath) {

     try {
        File src = new File(excelPath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
         wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
         sheet0 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 public int Rowcountcalculator()
 {
     int Rowcount = sheet0.getLastRowNum();
     return Rowcount;
 }
 public String passUNamePwd(int sheetnumb, int row, int column)
 {
     String data = wb.getSheetAt(sheetnumb).getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
     return data;
 }}
```

Comment: You might like https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/3166697

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It looks your excel data has some empty row and it is not handled properly in passUNamePwd method. Can you add the code for that method as well?

Answer (score 0):

Please check by changing your `passUNamePwd` as below

```
public String passUNamePwd(int sheetnumb, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{       
    XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(sheetnumb);
    String data="";

    Row row=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    Cell c=row.getCell(columnIndex, row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

    if(c==null){
        data="";
    }
    else{
        data=row.getCell(columnIndex).getStringCellValue();                
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I added but I got some warnings and error.


 Cell c=r.getCell(column, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL); - error here as "RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL cant be resolved or its not a field.



and warnings "the field CELL_TYPE_STRING is deprecated.
the method getCellType() from the type cell is deprecated." for  if(r.getCell(column).getCellType()==XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){

and the getCellType and CELL_TYPE_STRING are striked out

Comment: @KalaivaniBaskaran: I have updated the answer and please try with the updated one